# UIButton size is not as set in xib

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

I made UIButton with Type Custom in Interface Builder like below

[image: XIB in Interface Builder]

and its dimensions are

[image: Dimensions in Interface Builder]

But, when I run it on Ratina 4 Simulator,it show smaller

[image: Simulator Result]

Why is it showing like this, not like as was set in xib.

Comment: Since I see the "content hugging priority" in that screenshot: it looks like you are using Auto Layout. What are the constraints for that button?

Comment: Are you using auto layout (file inspector)? Autosizing (size inspector)?

Comment: I am using Auto Layout

Comment: Then set a fixed width constraint

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use auto layout. You can:make your button IBOutlet, connect with your UIButton object (shareBut for example) in code and write:

```
shareBut.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Or you can add  width constraint to your button in IB (look [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Interface_Builder)).

Comment: You need delete one of your button constraints (not width constraint). It will be Leading to space constraint or Trailing to space constraint. Or just set them (Trailing and Leading to space constraints) a priority, less then your button width constraint priority.

Answer (score 0):

The button might be larger, but you see only the image with it's original size. Try a larger image or set this one as background image (however in this case you can loose from the quality of the image)

Comment: This image is larget in pixel.

Comment: Check the ratio also (width/height) to be the same as the button's